# How to aggregate and sort real-time stout/logs on Mac?

Tags: macos, logging

I am developing a rails and scala application that uses MySQL, Redis, MongoDB and memcached on OSX.

It is rather annoying to always have 6 terminals open and go through the logs there, so I was wondering if there is a tool that allows me to launch the programs and then grab the stdout / log to socket (or logfile tail if that is the only output) and aggregate it with prefixes for the origin

```
[MySQL        - 00pid00] SELECT .......
[Rails Server - 11pid11] GET request to /foo
...
```

Ideally I can also sort and filter like [Apache Chainsaw](http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/) allows for log4j and create my own fields based on regex  (i.e. when there is an error, show me a field that only displays the URL of the error and the HTTP response / file + line that caused the error.

(I know sed awk grep and co, but a GUI is much easier to use and much faster to get started with)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can set up each of those systems to log to files, you can tail those logs from Chainsaw and aggregate the log entries into a single table.  Here's how:

- Pull down the latest developer snapshot of Chainsaw: http://people.apache.org/~sdeboy
- Select the 'Welcome' tab and click the 'View example receiver configuration' button at the top of the tab and copy the configuration
  -Create a number of VFSLogFilePatternReceiver entries, one for each log file you are going to tail.

  - The simplest logFormat is MESSAGE - it will place each log line in the MESSAGE field in a row in Chainsaw.
  - You can have Chainsaw parse the log line by using the fields defined in the LogFilePatternReceiver javadoc: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/receivers/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/varia/LogFilePatternReceiver.html
  - Note if your log format spans multiple lines you can use (LF) to represent a line feed (not yet in that JavaDoc)
- Once all of your log files are showing up in Chainsaw as separate tabs, you can collect all events from all tabs in a new tab by defining an expression which matches the events you'd like to see (see Help/Tutorial for documentation on expression syntax).

  - Hint: clear and pause the chainsaw-log tab (from the 'current tab' menu) in order to make sure chainsaw log messages aren't mixed in with yours
  - Select 'view, create tab from expression'
  - The simplest expression which will match all entries in all tabs is MSG EXISTS
  - a new tab with your expression will be created and populated with all existing events matching the expression
  - as new events arrive which match the expression, they will be added to the original tab as well as the expression tab

Answer (score 1):

You can add your own log files to the standard `/Applications/Utilities/Console.app`